# Can we join two parts of two composite primary keys together?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, composite-primary-key

I have to two tables, both have a composite primary key:

1. OrderNr + CustNr
2. OrderNr + ItemNr

Can I join both tables with the OrderNr and OrderNr which is each a part of a composite primary key?

Comment: `t1.OrderNr = t2.OrderNr`.

Comment: Learn what inner join on returns: rows of the cross join of the tables (which is a row for every combination of a row from each table) that satisfy the ON. Constraints (including PK) are irrelevant--the meanings of the input & output tables matter. What exactly do you mean by "join both tables with the OrderNr and OrderNr which is each a part of a composite primary key"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you may find you get rows from each table that repeat as they combine to make a unique combination. This is called a Cartesian product

```
Table A
OrderNr, CustNr
1,C1
1,C2
2,C1
2,C2

TableB
OrderNr,ItemNr
1,i1
1,i2


SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.OrderNr = b.OrderNr

1,C1,1,i1
1,C1,1,i2
1,C2,1,i1
1,C2,1,i2
```

This happens because composite primary keys can contain repeated elements so long as the combination of elements is unique. Joining on only one part of the PK, and that part being an element that is repeated (my custnr 1 repeats twice in each table, even though the itemnr and CustNr mean the rows are unique) results in a multiplied resultset - 2 rows from A that are custnr 1, multiplied by 2 rows from B that are custnr 1, gives 4 rows in total

> Does it work with the normal/naturla join too?

Normal joins (INNER, LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER, FULL OUTER) will join the rows from two tables or subqueries when the ON condition is valid. The clause in the ON is like a WHERE clause, yes - in that it represents a statement that is true or false (a predicate). If the statement is true, the rows are joined. You don't even have to make it about data from the tables - you can even say `a JOIN b ON 1=1` and every rows from A will get joined to every row from B. As commented, primary keys aren't involved in JOINS at all, though primary keys often rely on indexes and those indexes may be used to speed up a join, but they aren't vital to it.

Other joins (CROSS, NATURAL..) exist; a CROSS join is like the 1=1 example above, you don't specify an ON, every row from A is joined to every row from B, by design. NATURAL JOIN is one to avoid using, IMHO - the database will look for column names that are the same in both tables and join on them. The problem is that things can stop working in future if someone adds a column with the same name but different content/meaning to the two tables. No serious production system I've ever come across has used NATURAL join. You can get away with some typing if your columns to join on are named the same, with USING - `SELECT * FROM a JOIN b USING (col)` - here both A and B have a column called `col`. USING has some advantages, especially over NATURAL join, in that it doesn't fall apart if another column of the same name as an existing one but it has some detractors too - you can't say `USING(col) AND ...`. Most people just stick to writing ON, and forget USING

NATURAL join also does NOT use primary keys. There is no join style (that I know of) that will look at a foreign key relationship between two tables and use that as the join condition

> And then is it true that if I try to join Primary key and foreign key of two tables, that it works like a "where" command?

Hard to understand what you mean by this, but if you mean that `A JOIN B ON A.primarykey = B.primary_key_in_a` then it'll work out, sure. If you mean `A CROSS JOIN B WHERE A.primarykey = B.primary_key_in_a` then that will also work, but it's something I'd definitely avoid - no one writes SQLs this way, and the general favoring is to drop use of WHERE to create joining conditions (you do still see people writing the old school way of `FROM a,b WHERE a.col=b.col` but it's also heavily discouraged), and put them in the ON instead

So, in summary:

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.col1 = b.col2
```

Joins all rows from a with all rows from b, where the values in col1 equal the values in col2. No primary keys are needed for any of this to work out

Comment: Okay so its tecnically possible. But isnt there any problem, because OrderNr alone is not a primary key, because its not unique? I mean If I only call OrderNr, then how does SQL know which OrderNr I mean? I thought it would be nonsense, because of this reason

Comment: If the relationship is not one to one your result will be multiplied check my answer for it

Comment: Okay so the only problem is that I get the row "OrderNr" duplicated, apart from that its alright to do that?

Comment: you can do it but your resulting records will be duplicated. There are ways to handle this but it totally depends on what you need to see.

Comment: Sure, you can join anything to anything.. `SELECT * FROM musicartists a INNER JOIN jobtitles j ON a.artistname = J.jobtitle` will successfully join the band named "snow patrol" to the job of the same name. In writing the query and saying `ON x = y` you ask the database to link everything in this table with everything in that table where the values are the same. Primary keys don't have anything to do with joins, per se - you can join tables together that don't have primary keys

Comment: @CaiusJard Okay, I dont know why I thought that it only would work with Primary/Foreign keys. Does it work with the normal/naturla join too? And then is it true that if I try to join Primary key and foreign key of two tables, that it works like a "where" command?

Comment: I'll add some info to the answer for that one, it's a bit more involved than a  comment

Comment: You already answered my second question here 
"The clause in the ON is like a WHERE clause, yes -"
But what I exactly meant was a.primary-key = b.foreign-key, but that should be the same. Thanks for the help

Comment: ON and WHERE do differ slightly when you're using LEFT/RIGHT/FULL outer joins. `a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id AND b.name = 'something'` will work properly, `a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.name = 'something'` will behave like an INNER join, not a LEFT join, because requiring b.name to have a value will remove all the NULL rows that LEFT join generates when it cannot find a match

Comment: I don't recognize your classification of 'normal joins' and 'other joins' at all. There is nothing /normal/ about an outer join which is actually a union!

Comment: "There is no join style... that will look at a foreign key relationship between two tables" - while that would perhaps make for a neat query builder /tool/, it makes no sense in a data manipulation /language/ ...which is exactly why such "join styles" do not exist in SQL.

Comment: For "normal" read "typical". Other than that I'm not entirely sure what point you're making; can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can join any table if there is/are logical relationship between them

```
select *
from t1
JOIN t2 
  on t1.ORderNr = t2.OrderNr
```

Although if `OrderNr` cannot provide unicity between tables by itself, your data will be multiplied.

Lets say that you have 2 OrderNr with value 1 on t1 and 5 OrderNr with value 1 on t2, when you join them, you will get 2 x 5 = 10 records.

Comment: You can even join tables if there isn't a logical relationship, though "just because you can, doesn't mean you should" :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is similar to a problem commonly referred to as a "fan trap".  (If you had an "order" table keyed solely by `OrderNr` if would exactly be a fan trap).

Either way, it's the same problem -- the relationship between Order/Customers and Order/Items is ambiguous.  You cannot tell which customers ordered which items.

It is technically possible to join these tables -- you can join on any columns regardless of whether they are key columns or not.  The problem is that your results will probably not make sense, unless you have more conditions and other tables that you are not telling us about.

For example, a simple join just on `t1.OrderNr = t2.OrderNr` will return rows indicating every customer related to the order has ordered every item related to the order.  If that is what you want, you have no problem here.

Comment: Exactly thats what I wanted to know under @Caius Jards answer. Thank you. And yeah there is more in the table, but I think the problem will stay:


`ORDER (O#, Odate, Cust#, Total_amount) 
ORDER-ITEM (O#, I#, Qty_ordered, Total_price, Discount%)`

I have to join both tables with a join, and then have to show what the schema would look like, what the candidate key is, have to show what the functional dependencies are and if the schema fullfills 2nd and 3rd normalform. 
I came to this join result:
`Or-OrI(O#, Odate, Cust#, Total_amount, O#, I#, 
Qty_ordered, Total_price, Discount%)`